# An if/else condition in python

Tags: python

```
print 'enter a number'

s = raw_input()

s = float(s)

q = int(s)

if s == q:

    print 'it is an integer'

else:

    print 'it is not an integer'
```

When someone inputs a letter, it should display "it is not an integer", however we would still want this to be done with if/else condition. Does somebody know how to do that? We got an answer to this but the answer did not contain if/else anymore.

Comment: "Please post the full code in here" is not a good way to invite users to help you...

Comment: check the first comment you received, wrapping the casting to int/float in a try except block is the best way to go with this

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
print 'enter a number'

s = raw_input()

if not s.isdigit():
   print("it is not an integer")
   # do further stuff
```